# How to check if all values in array are the same?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

Lets say I have an array `short int check[10] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};`.
I want to check if all the element are the same.
I can't find the answer in `stackoverflow` nor `google`, but I've come across this code in `C++`.

```
bool aresame(int a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    unordered_map<int, int> m;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        m[a[i]]++;
    }
    if (m.size() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Adjust a bit, and the result is huge error.
My attempt is using`if's` but that's very un-professional.
Might as well know, is there are any other ways to do it?

Comment: Why is using `if`s unprofessional? Iterate over the array and check it against the first entry. `for (i=1; i<n; ++i) if (a[i] != a[0]) return false; return true;`

Comment: You found that C++ code, but you need a solution in C? Then don't waste time with that code. Did you try with some simple and straight forward approach like "loop over each index and check if that element is same as first element"? What went wrong with your own attempts?

Comment: Using `if` is only unprofessional if you use it in unprofessional way. Nothing wrong with `if` if used properly.

Comment: Using `if` in a for loop is far more "professional" than incrementing elements of a map.

Comment: Remember if you always `return` in one branch of an `if` then everything past that becomes an `else` by default so you can skip that part and collapse it down a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if`  is perfectly fine, there is nothing *unprofessional* about it.

I should note that in `short int check[10] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};` only 9 elements are 1, the last element will be initialized to 0, so this check will always be `false`, if you omit the size ***i.e.*** `check[] = {1,1,1...` you won't have this problem because the size of the array will be deduced by the number of elements in the initializer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool aresame(short int a[], size_t n) // added value to check
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != a[0])
            return false; // if a different value is found return false
    }
    return true; // if it reaches this line, all the values are the same
}

int main()
{
    short int check[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    printf("%s", aresame(check, sizeof check / sizeof *check) ? "true" : "false");
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OROpAFOoMLllv4w0)

Answer (score 3):

As [Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782754/gerhardh) pointed out in the comments, there is nothing unprofessional about using `if`. This code should work:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool are_same(int *arr, unsigned int len)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
        if (arr[0] != arr[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

You can call the function `are_same` like this:

```
int arr[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
unsigned int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
printf("The elements in the array are %s.\n",
       are_same(arr, len) ? "all the same" : "not all the same");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not like if statements then try this:

```
bool aresame(int a[], int n) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i<n && a[i]==a[0]) 
        i++;
    return i == n;
}
```

No need to use extra local storage, just loop until you see an element that is not the same. If you reach the end, everything is fine. Otherwise not.

See here: https://godbolt.org/z/8r6YK6W34

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness here's a recursive version (no explicit `if`s) :

```
bool aresame(int a[],int n){
    return (n <= 1) || (a[0] == a[n-1] && aresame(a, n-1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty `if`-less implementation assuming two's complement without padding bits:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool are_same(const int *arr, size_t n) {
    return n == 0 || !memcmp(arr, arr + 1, (n - 1) * sizeof(*arr));
}
```

You can generalize this method to check if the array contains a repeating sequence of length `r`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool is_repeating(const int *arr, size_t n, size_t r) {
    return n <= r || !memcmp(arr, arr + r, (n - r) * sizeof(*arr));
}
```